# Why does composer -v return a PHP startup warning for php_fileinfo.dll?

Tags: php, dll, warnings

When I run the following command: `composer -v` I get a warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_fileinfo.dll' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_fileinfo.dll: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_fileinfo.dll' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_fileinfo.dll: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Please help me to understand why this occurs and how to resolve it.

Comment: if you want to remove this library you can comment in php.ini. for more detail. http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

Comment: A `.dll` and a linux type path (`/usr/lib`) looks out of place

Comment: @axiac My mistake...if I could tun back time

Comment: Yes,I found. 
Because php_fileinfo.dll is enabled in file /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The path of the missing file (`/usr/lib/php/20151012`) tells me that you are experiencing this issue on an Unix-like OS (Linux or macOS). But the name of the file (`php_fileinfo.dll`) is specific to Windows. These two don't match.

The problem is that the PHP is configured to load an extension it cannot find and load. The error is in the `php.ini` file.

On macOS and Linux systems the `php.ini` file usually stays in `/etc` but it can be located in other places too. The safest way to find it is to ask PHP where it loads it from.

Open a Terminal and run:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

You will get an output that looks similar to this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php
```

Put `/php.ini` after the path provided and open the file in your favorite editor. For example, using `vi` and my setup, the command is:

```
vi /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

Scroll through the file (or use the "search" functionality of your editor) until you find a block of lines that start like this:

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
...
```

Make sure all the lines of this type (`extension=php_***.dll`) start with a semicolon (`;`). The semicolon in front of the line makes it a comment; PHP will ignore the line and will not try to load the Windows extension.